# Chrome Extension: How to make background wait executescript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've recently started developing my first Google Chrome Extension, and am experiencing an issue. In my **background.js** script each second I call **script.js**, smth like:

***script.js:***

```
/* Some code */
if (condition1) {
    setTimeout(func1, 500);
    result = 1;
} else
if (condition2) {
    setTimeout(func2, 4000);
    result = 2;
} else
/*Some code */

result
```

***background.js:***

```
function func() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'script.js'},
        function (result) {
            console.log(result[0]);
        }
    );    

    /* Some code using results of scipt.js */
};

var interval = null;
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == "addon") {
        if (interval != null) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        } else {
            interval = setInterval(func, 1000);
        }
    }
};

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Addon", "id": "addon"});
}
```

So i need call script each max(1 second, after previous executeScript). It should work in this way:

```
1. If previous script.js finished and 1 second after previous 
    interval call passed, call new script.js
2. If previos script.js finished and 1 second after previous 
    interval call haven't passed, wait for 1 second and call new script.js
3. If previous script.js haven't finished, wait until it finish 
    and if 1 second passed, call new script.js
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.executeScript` callback expects a synchronous result. Your logic however is asynchronous. In such cases you have to set up a proper [inter-process communication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4M_a7xejYI).

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'script.js'});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     if (request.action === 'done') {
         console.log(request.result);
         // some code
         sendResponse({ action: 'next', arg: 2 });
     }

     // uncomment this if code is also asynchronous
     // return true;
});

// optional
// chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
//     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'next', arg: 1 });
// });
```

**script.js**

```
function func1() {
    // some code
    var result = 1;
    done(result);
}
function func1(2) {
    // some code
    var result = 2
    done(result);
}

function runAction(which) {
    switch (which) {
        case 1: setTimeout(func1, 500); break;
        case 2: setTimeout(func2, 500); break;
    }
}

function done(result) {
    var msg = { action: 'done', result: result }};
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function(response) {
        if (response.action === 'next') {
            runAction(response.arg);
        }
    });
}

// start
runAction(1);
```

Comment: As I understand scipt.js should be a content-script ? Also could you suggest how to send response == "next" first time to start this loop?

Comment: @ДенисСвидунович not necessarily a content-script. You can set it up as previously, with `executeScript`. The `runAction(1)` line starts it for you normally but you can message the tab directly. Answer updated

Comment: Hey, i have, one more question. If there is any way to check if no response after 10 sec, send one more message?